# Am I doing this split, reverse, join correctly?

Tags: javascript, join, split, reverse

Having a little trouble understanding what this does. If I have a string,

Using `"Mcdonalds"` as an example, I do:

```
"McDonalds".split("").reverse().join();
```

What exactly am I doing?

Am I splitting each character `(M c D o n a l d s)`, then  reversing it `(s d l a n o D c M)` then joining to get `(sdlanoDcM)`? (Trying to see if I understand this right)

Comment: No it's not at all, but thanks for your input.

Comment: Read the documentation for each function being called: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: What you want is to reverse a string, isn't?

Comment: @ronnyfm No I was just trying to understand what happens when you use all three at once :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure you specify an empty string to [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), otherwise you'll get commas between each character:

```
"McDonalds".split("").reverse().join(""); // "sdlanoDcM"
```

Comment: okay thank you, I thought this is what it was doing, just trying to make sure

Comment: if I wanted to take in a string as an argument inside a function, and split it would I just do this then?:

var h = "helloworld!";
function splitString(h)
{
h.split("");
return h;
}

Comment: @user3308129 Split returns a new array. It doesn't modify the variable, `h`. Try `function splitString(h) { return h.split(""); }`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `sdlanoDcM`

then use `""` inside `.join()`:

```
alert("McDonalds".split("").reverse().join(""));
```